# PHPUnit : mock an Interface and super class at the same time

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have an interface :

```
interface MyInterface {

   const SOME_CONSTANT='hi';

   function method(): void;
}
```

and a super class :

```
class MyClass {

   private $id;

   function method1(){
       //do something
   }
}
```

I need to get a mock that implements the interface and extends the super class,i.e mock needs to be of type MyInterface and MyClass at the same time.

the `TestCase::createMock` method can take just one class to mock so I was hoping to see if it's possible to get the mock I need using PHPUnit 6.

Answer (score 4):

You could use some prophecy here.

```
class ClassAndInterfaceTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    function classAndIface ()
    {
        $myclass_instance = $this->prophesize (MyClass::class)
            ->willImplement (MyInterface::class)->reveal ();

        $this->a ($myclass_instance);
        $this->b ($myclass_instance);
    }

    function a (MyInterface $i)
    {
    }

    function b (MyClass $i)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add a space between call (and define) parenthesis. Thanks ;)